# Stop GridView from responding to Page up/Page down keys

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp

I have a grid view in my uwp app that responds to the selection changed event. I need to make that event to stop triggering when pressing the page up/page down buttons, since I want a custom behavior for them (which is changing the page one at a time).

Some things I tried:

- IsTabStop="false"
- Using ItemClick instead of SelectionChanged
- Setting handled to true in my other keyboard listener
- Searching for a way to prevent the grid view from getting focus

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution. Listen to the GotFocus-event of the GridView, and pass the focus on to another component whenever it gets focus.

Xaml-tag of the GridView:

```
GotFocus="GridView_GotFocus"
```

In the GridView:

```
private void GridView_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Shift focus to SomeOtherComponent
    SomeOtherComponent.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
}
```